# Visual Studio 2005 Software

Tags: visual-studio-2005

May be not serious question/stupid question but I tried searching in internet for Visual Studio 2005 software (I mean free download :) ) but couldn't find a place where I can get it.

Do you guys know any site from where I can download the software. If yes, can you please share the link with me.

Comment: The older versions have not been released as freeware, so if you don't want to pay for a license, the Express edition is your only option. More importantly though, is why you feel like you need to use VS 2005 instead of a newer version like VS 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all Microsoft Express tools from here

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

2005 is no longer on the main page (if available at all), but seriously consider 2010 or 2008 editions.

Answer (score 0):

The free versions of visual studio can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Comment: But this are trial version for 30 days trial or so. Ahh!!! probably I should try once.

Comment: Not the trial versions - the express versions.  They are free.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for Visual studio Web Developer Express 2005, as opposed to C#, Cnet's got it here:

http://download.cnet.com/Visual-Web-Developer-2005-Express-Edition/3000-10250_4-10421166.html

Now only if they had an edition that works with Windows 7...